# Iframe Change Content CSS Style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I do have an iframe inside my webpage, but i want to change the css / font styles etc.

```
<iframe name='iframe1' id="iframe1" src='<?php echo "http://micro.shoretel.com/www/?v=$version&s=$style&l=$logo&p=" . $_GET["p"] ?>' frameborder='0' width='660' height='450'></iframe>
```

How do i override the CSS style of the iframe's content?

Comment: Is the `iframe` src on your domain? If so you can use standard CSS to muck with it, if not... well then you can't do anything.

Comment: put the style sheet references on the iframe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/css-overide-body-style-for-content-in-iframe

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*If the `iframe` loads a page on your own domain*, and you want to *statically* change the `iframe`s styles, you could just change the style rules in the CSS file, this is what @Justin808 is referring to.

However if you want to *dynamically* change the styles, *and the `iframe` loads a page on your own domain*, you could do this using jQuery:

```
$("iframe").contents().find("element-selector").css("border-color", "blue");
```

*If the `iframe` loads a page on another domain*, you're out of luck, follow [this link](http://blog.cakemail.com/the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem/), where you can read up a bit on why that doesn't work.

*If you're using HTML5*, you can use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage) to communicate between the page and the `iframe`.

*@crdunst*'s solution will work *if you have "editing access" to the page inside the `iframe`* so that you can edit it to understand the parameters which are passed to it, and then make it act upon those parameters. It is not as dynamic as using jQuery as it only allows you to change styles by reloading the page inside the `iframe` and passing it another set of parameters.

Comment: ill try the jQuery, thanks,

Comment: It doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is what user2146515 is referring to, but if you have access to the page within the iframe, you could pass values on the url, and then use those values within your iframe content:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youriframecontent.com?bg=ffffff&text=000000"></iframe>
```

Then within the iframe page, check for the value and add styles based on those values