# Remove time from embedded Google Calendar

Tags: iframe, google-calendar-api

I was wondering if there is any way to remove the time infornt of the events in a google calendar.

[image: Time takes up too much room]

Because now the events are very poorly visible

Comment: Any luck with this solution? Did you ever find a work around?

Answer (score 0):

If the embedded calendar was from the same domain, you could override the CSS for the `<span>` elements that contain the time.

```
.te-t { display: none !important; }
```

However, since the iframe is from YouTube, this is not possible due to cross domain security policies. More details in the links below.

- [CSS override body style for content in iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/css-override-body-style-for-content-in-iframe)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Another solution would be to use the Agenda view instead of of Month view. It's certainly not the same but it has infinite scroll which allows you to see upcoming days and months. And, addressing your original issue, there is plenty of space for the event times and descriptions.

[image: Google Calendar Embedded Agenda]