# An issue with cursor in an iframe

Tags: css, iframe, cursor

Recently I've started dealing with CSS and I am stuck with a "cursor isssue".

I've tried to find a solution online but no succeed.

I have nested an iframe in a parent directory and I wanted to place a customized cursor both in a parent directory and in the iframe itself. The parent dir works fine but there is a problem with the iframe.

As long as the cursor is over a content it's customized according the the code.
But when it moves underneath the text it gets back to the default pointer.

How to make it look customized in a whole iframe not matter if over or not over any kind of content?

The typical CSS underneath:

```
cursor: url(images/cursor.cur), auto;
```

Comment: And if you set `color: red` for your webpage, does it mean that embed page text also should become red?

Comment: any ideas ? sorry for spamming.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6495816/949476