# Append style tags to head using JS and iframe

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I'm trying to find a quick and dirty solution to style some iframe content.

I found this solution which seems perfect for what I want (very old legacy site that doesn't have to be perfect) but I can't get it working.

What this should do is append the `<style>` I've defined to the `<head>` within my iframe.

```
window.onload = styleOffers;
function styleOffers(){
console.log('running');
$('iframe').load( function() {
    $('iframe').contents().find("head")
      .append($("<style type='text/css'>#offer4{outline:1px solid red;}</style>"));
});
}
```

But I don't seem to see any style being applied to `#offer4`

`console.log` does confirm it's running the function. Just no style appending :(

Comment: Is the iFrame from the same domain as the parent?

Comment: No it is not. I tried using AJAX but couldn't because it is a different domain. Hence trying this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible if the iFrame does not belong to the same domain as the parent. From the [comment section below the answer from which you got the script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13959836/464188):

> "Only works if the iFrame content is from the same parent domain."

Moreover, the [accepted answer to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6495816/464188) covers this point. If modifying external pages through iFrames were possible, numerous XSS vulnerabilities would be introduced, so unfortunately what you are trying to achieve is not possible.