# overwrite /customize css in iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

i have a site which a plugin for comments which loads an iframe
on iphone and ipad the pages crash and browser quits,
this turned out to be from :

```
 display:-webkit-box;
 display:-webkit-flex;
```

these are being inherited from the site's main css,

i tried adding in css something like:

```
   iframe .textbox { display:block }
```

to overwrite the inherited properties and make it work,
but the elements don't seem to be reading my css declaration;

how can i fix this please?
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply CSS to iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An iframe is a 'hole' in your page that displays another web page inside of it. The contents of the iframe is not in any shape or form part of your parent page.

Credits : [CSS override body style for content in iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/css-override-body-style-for-content-in-iframe/6495816#6495816)
So modifying is not an option i guess.

Thanks

Comment: When you copy and paste an answer from another SO question, it's considered bad form. Instead, post the link to the answer to give credit to the person who actually wrote it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6495816/1556245. Downvote.

Comment: Thanks for updating, downvote removed. More to the point, if a question is answered somewhere else, that usually means it's a duplicate question. Instead of answering, flag it as a duplicate (using the 'flag' link underneath the question).