# Change underline color for Disqus tabs

Tags: css, disqus

How to change [underline color for tabs](https://monosnap.com/image/d6ZBxZZYw3bUISyjDJaBWlmQC4Xh2D) in disqus on my site?

I tried to rewrite disqus rules by own:

```
.nav-primary>ul>li.active>a:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000 !important;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: 0;
}
.active .publisher-nav-color::after {
    background: #000 !important;
}
```

My rules has no effect (because of iframe, suppose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The active tab underline color can't be changed. Disqus uses the default link color of the page it's on. If it is using a different color other than your link color, make sure your main <a> color style is inheritable by Disqus.

See the "Link color" section: https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/545277-disqus-appearance-tweaks

Answer (score 0):

`a:after` -> `a::after`

`.nav-primary>ul>li.active>a:after {background: #000 !important;}`

should be

`.nav-primary > ul > li.active > a::after {background: #000 !important;}`

Comment: may be because inside iFrame check here 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/css-override-body-style-for-content-in-iframe

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question: Styles cannot be applied to iframes because they are a different source. You might want to check [Disqus's Appearance Tweaking guide](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/545277-disqus-appearance-tweaks) which shows you how to make css tweaks.

Comment: Thanks. I already read this article. It doesn't describe any way to solve my problem. But I saw a lot of websites with custom underline color.