# How to edit an Embedded Webpages' Stylesheet?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I would overwrite the css inside of an embedded webpage

```
<object data=http://omitted.com style="width: 100%; height: 1500px">
<embed src=http://omitted.com width=”100%″ height=”100%″> </embed>
</object>
```

This is the method I am using to embed the website and I would like to hide a division inside the embedded webpage.

I tried putting a style tag in the actual page(not embedded) cause I cannot edit the actual embedded page.

Comment: Nope. Pull the page in with an AJAX call, add the CSS to the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

[CSS override body style for content in iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/css-override-body-style-for-content-in-iframe)