# How to apply CSS to external iframe?

Tags: css, iframe

I have been taught that one **can not** apply CSS to cross origin iframes, but I have found that [**Stylebot**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) applies CSS to iframes successfully with no problem at all.

1. How is this possible?
2. Is there any chance I can do the same in my website?

Comment: Chrome extensions are not limited by cross-origin restrictions

Comment: This has been asked before.  Take a look here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/css-override-body-style-for-content-in-iframe

Answer (score 2):

You can't apply custom `CSS` to cross-origin `iframe` ( you can only if you have direct access to the both servers )

But..

Extensions can avoid those rules because files in extensions have different policy rules. So basically you can add a `JavaScript` file to each and every page or `iframe`. And from there you can basically do anything. And this `JavaScript` file that was injected by your extension will never be blocked. Each and every browser has its own API, about `Chrome`'s way of doing things you can read here :
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

About extensions you can read here:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Comment: I already stated that that's what I have been taught.

- It's very clear stylebot is an extension
- It's very clear extensions are installed manually
- It's very clear CSS *can't* be applied directly to iframes.

Nevertheless extensions ignore these rules.

**Can you explain to me (in a practical way) how extensions make it possible?**

Comment: Plz look at the update.

Comment: Definitely much better.