# Remove background color in google docs viewer

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-framework2, google-docs

I am using google docs viewer to show pdf in my zf2 website but while showing that in Iframe it automatically showing grey background.

Is there any way to remove that background.

HTML Code:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsamplepdf.com%2Fsample.pdf&embedded=true" width="400" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

js fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Amit_Jadli/34zoyaba/5/

Please Help me on this,

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/css-override-body-style-for-content-in-iframe

Comment: @NooBskie thanks for reply, but that link doesn't working for me i had checked that solutions, as i am displaying pdf in iframe, i dont know how the css class adding to the iframe, may be it is from google side..