# How to access a hidden div in an iframe?

Tags: css, css-selectors

For the life of me, I cannot figure how to get to this div...

- div#someId

  - iframe

    - html>head>body

      - div.wrapper
      - div.footer

Of course, my attempt:

```
#someId iframe body .footer
```

does not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/css-override-body-style-for-content-in-iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the style of a page displayed in an iframe unless you have direct access and therefore ownership of the source html and/or css files.

This has been covered many times before...