# iframe with unknown url(domain, host ) needs to be modified?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a site with an iframe having a source url which is provided by my client. I need to resolve an alignment issue inside that iframe, when I try to achieve it through script since there is everything different in that iframe src (domain,host,port) I was blocked by cross-site scripting issue and since it is an url from my client I don't have access to include anything in it.

**EDIT:**
I like to say that I have already tried

- post message
- document.domain
- crossdomain option in jquery

Post message option and document.domain option wants me to include some scripts in the frames target URL, which is not possible in my case since I don't have access to it.

Jquery Ajax cross domain is a one is only for domain(http,https), which is not my case, everything is different here.

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/css-override-body-style-for-content-in-iframe) pointed out as duplicate also I have tried already, the second one seems to be close but it won't go beyond cross site script issue. I am not sure the accepted answer(YOU CAN'T) here is the final one.

Comment: You can't change anything inside an iFrame if the page it contains is not on the same server as the parent file

Comment: Does a wyswig editor's iframe load source from an another url?

Comment: Nope, it's loading from the local textbox.

Comment: Then how it could be the duplicate, my ques is about source which you won't have any control on it.

Comment: If you don’t have any control over the source, then you can not do this client-side.

Comment: "I am not sure the accepted answer(YOU CAN'T) here is the final one." — Why not? Even if it isn't, surely the answers belong on the duplicate question?

Comment: <div class='framef'><iframe src="client_url" ></iframe></div> I said can not have any access on the place client_url contents,