# CSS styles not applying to page displayed in an iframe

Tags: php, html, css, iframe

I have an external CSS file that I `<link>` into the files that I'm running. Some of the styles are applied but others are not. I have followed the syntax that I've found in other places like W3Schools and other questions here. But I still cannot get some of them to work. The `hover` works, but the `collapse-border: collapse` does not. And neither do the `background-color` lines. Here is what I've got in the css file:

```
#OuterTable tr:hover{background-color: #f5f5f5;}
#OuterTable {border-collapse: collapse;}
#OuterTable tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #fff;}
#OuterTable tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #e5e5e5;}

#MaterialByState tr:hover{background-color: #f5f5f5}
#MaterialByState tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #fff}
#MaterialByState tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #e5e5e5}
#MaterialByState {border-collapse: collapse}
```

The #Name are ID's for tables that I am displaying in an iFrame on the main page when i click on a link. The tables display, they just are not formatted the way that I want them to be and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I've tried with and without the `;` as soon above and neither way makes a difference. I can get the `collapse-border: collapse` to work if I put it in the file that has the table, but the other lines about the background color don't work when placed there. And I want them to all be in the same place so that I can update them all in the same place instead of hunting through my code for the tables. I'm using PHP code to pull data from a DB so it's not the prettiest or easiest to go through.

**EDIT**
I am using a main page to link to the other pages and display them in an iFrame. On the other pages that I'm displaying I have the css linked in them in the files that call the other tables:

```
<?php
$servername = "Server";
$username = "User";
$password = "Password";
$dbname = "DBName";
echo '<link rel="StyleSheet" href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css">';
```

So that the HTML in the iFrame looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>QDef</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>This will pull down all the Queries from the QDef table</h2>
<link rel="StyleSheet" href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css">
```

and the CSS looks like it does above.

**Edit**

Here is the QDef.php file that I am trying to display in the iFrame:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>QDef</title>
    <!--style type="text/css">
        table
        {
            border-collapse: collapse
        }
       #OuterTable tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #fff}
       #OuterTable tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #e5e5e5}
       #OuterTable tr:hover{background-color: #f5f5f5}
    </style-->
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>This will pull down all the Queries from the QDef table</h2>
<?php
$servername = "Server";
$username = "User";
$password = "Password";
$dbname = "DBName";
echo '<link rel="StyleSheet" href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css">';
try
{
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$servername;database=$dbname", $username,$password);
    //set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT, 1);
    echo "Connected Successfully<br>" /*. $conn*/;
    /*If conncected see if we can pull any data!*/
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) ); 
}

$tsql = "select Id,QSrc,QName,isActive,RunReport,FilePath,QDef from pmdb.v_QDefs";
//echo $tsql . "<br>";
$getqueries = $conn->query($tsql);

$queries = $getqueries->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$countqueries = count($queries);

if(isset($countqueries))
{    
    if($countqueries > 0)
    {
        //echo "There are queries returned";

        BeginQueriesTable($countqueries);
        foreach($queries as $query)
        {
            PopulateQueryTable($query);
        }
        EndQueriesTable();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<br>Values returned: $countqueries";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "No count";
}

function BeginQueriesTable($rowCount)
{
    $headings = array("Id","QSrc","QName","isActive","RunReport","FilePath","QDef");
    echo "<table align='center' cellpadding='5' border='1' id=" . chr(34) . "OuterTable" . chr(34) . ">";
    echo "<thead valign=" . chr(34) . "top" . chr(34) . ">";
    echo "<tr>$rowCount Results</tr><tr bgcolor='silver'>";
    foreach ($headings as $heading)
    {
        echo "<th class=" . chr(34) . "cell" . chr(34) . ">$heading</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

function PopulateQueryTable($values)
{
    //$queryID = $values['ID'];
    echo "<tbody valign=" . chr(34) . "top" . chr(34) . "><tr>";
    foreach($values as $key=>$value)
    {
        if (!is_null($value))
        {
            echo "<td white-space: nowrap style overflow-x: scroll>$value</td>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<td>N/A</td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

function EndQueriesTable()
{
    echo "</tbody></table><br/>";
}

?>        
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS file is already showing above.

Here is the Main Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TestingSwitchingMainPage</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table
        {
            border-collapse: collapse
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="style.php" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <UL>
        <LI><A Href="MainPage.aspx" target="MainPage">Main</A>
        <LI><A Href="QDef.php" target="MainPage">Material Tracking QDef</A>
        <LI><A Href="MaterialTrackingAllStates.php" target="MainPage">Material Tracking All rows with State</A>
        <LI><A Href="SearchStateProject.php" target="MainPage">Material Tracking Searh by State or Project Number</A>
        <LI><A Href="TestPHP.php" target="MainPage">Material Tracking PHP Info</A>
    </UL>
    <iframe src="MainPage.aspx" Width=100% Height=750 name="MainPage" FrameBorder=0>
        This will show up if the browser doesn't understand IFrame.
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know if this will make it any clearer for you as I'm using php to pull data from a SQL Server and then display that in a table.Which is supposed to show in the iFrame. I can pull the QDef.php file up by itself and the styling is still not being applied. I'm testing this in IE11 if that makes any difference. I want it to be able to be used regardless what browser I'm using.

**EDIT 2**

I have made some changes to my CSS file based on recommendations from W3C Validation Checker that was recommended from @Mr Lister. It now look like this:

```
#OuterTable tr:hover{background-color: #0094ff;}
#OuterTable {border-collapse: collapse;}
#OuterTable tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #fff !important;} iFrame
#OuterTable tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #e5e5e5 !important;} iFrame

#MaterialByState tr:hover{background-color: #0094ff}
#MaterialByState tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #fff}
#MaterialByState tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #e5e5e5}
#MaterialByState {border-collapse: collapse}

#OuterTable, td, th {border:  1px solid black}
#OuterTable, thead {text-align: left}
#OuterTable {text-align: left}
#OuterTable, td, th {white-space: nowrap}
#OuterTable, td, th {vertical-align: bottom}
th {background-color: #808080; color: #fff}
td, th {padding: 5px}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #fff}
tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #e5e5e5}

#OuterTable thead, table tbody {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: left;
}

#OuterTable tbody {
    width:  100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

#OuterTable tbody:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
}

#OuterTable tbody:nth-child(even) {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
}
```

I have taken pretty much all the table formatting out of the HTML and put it in the CSS file. So far everything is working except making the rows alternate color. I have added the code that I've found in several different ways to try and get it to work. I've got `#OuterTable tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #fff !important;} iFrame` and I've got this `tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #fff}` and I've got this `#OuterTable tbody:nth-child(even) {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
}`

None of these various ways are working when everything else for this page is. What else can I do to get this working??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS override body style for content in iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/css-override-body-style-for-content-in-iframe)

Comment: I just added an edit. This is not a duplicate to the other question. I don't have any other formatting or styling other than the CSS file

Comment: I tried adding `!important` to the lines I am trying to have take effect, no change.

Comment: Still trying to style an iframe

Comment: Would the CSS not apply to the table that is being displayed? I have it linked in the file that is being called and displayed in the iFrame?

Comment: iframe, what iframe? there's nothing to support the question with. Plus, you   may have to add `iframe` to your CSS rules. I.e. `iframe #OuterTable {border-collapse: collapse;}` or `iframe` at the end of it etc., and remember that id's are unique as is letter-case is important, should it be the case. Try putting your stylesheet inside `<head></head>` also.

Comment: Adding `iFrame` in the CSS did nothing. I did know that the `id` is case sensitive and have made sure that they are correct. I also tried adding the link for the css in the `<head></head>` , but again this did nothing.

Comment: Google "how to style an iframe css stackoverflow" ("stackoverflow" being optional), and you'll get quite a few hits. You can also use an inline styling method which will work but will be rather long. It may not be possible without using JS/jQuery.

Comment: Can you show some more code? Like a working demo? By the way, please note that `tr` elements do not have backgrounds. Yes, you can give one a background property, and it gets inherited into the `td`s, but the `tr`s themselves do not use the background whatsoever.

Comment: The `link` is in the body because it is in the `<?php ?>`. It does seem to work when it's not in the `<?php ?>`. I have tried having it in the `<head></head>`, but nothing happens.

Comment: The comment above should say that it doesn't seem to work when it's not in the `<?php ?>`.

Comment: You have errors in your table. E.G. `<td white-space: nowrap style overflow-x: scroll>`. Run the resulting HTML through the W3C validator. Also, the `bgcolor` attributes may interfere with the CSS for the backgrounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get the style `tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #fff}
tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #e5e5e5}` to work, but I did find a work around. I gave the `<tr></tr>` a class. I alternated the class with 2 different class names (row and row1) then made an update to my css to have `.row1 {background-color: #fff}
.row {background-color: #e5e5e5}` This gave me the banded rows that I was looking to get and couldn't with the other way I was trying. I also had to update the PHP script to do the alternating of the class like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>QDef</title>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>This will pull down all the Queries from the QDef table</h2>
<?php
$servername = "Server";
$username = "User";
$password = "Password";
$dbname = "DBName";
echo '<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">';
try
{
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$servername;database=$dbname", $username,$password);
    //set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT, 1);
    echo "Connected Successfully<br>" /*. $conn*/;
    /*If conncected see if we can pull any data!*/
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) ); 
}

$tsql = "select Id,QSrc,QName,isActive,RunReport,FilePath,QDef from pmdb.v_QDefs";
//echo $tsql . "<br>";
$getqueries = $conn->query($tsql);

$queries = $getqueries->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$countqueries = count($queries);

if(isset($countqueries))
{    
    if($countqueries > 0)
    {
        //echo "There are queries returned";

        BeginQueriesTable($countqueries);
          $CountValues = 1;     /**********Added************/
        foreach($queries as $query)
        {
            PopulateQueryTable($query,$CountValues);/******Updated******/
            $CountValues = !$CountValues;/***********Added**************/
        }
        EndQueriesTable();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<br>Values returned: $countqueries";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "No count";
}

function BeginQueriesTable($rowCount)
{
    $headings = array("Id","QSrc","QName","isActive","RunReport","FilePath","QDef");
    echo "<p>$rowCount Results</p>";
    echo "<table class=" . chr(34) . "tab" .chr(34) . "id=" . chr(34) . "OuterTable" . chr(34) . ">";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($headings as $heading)
    {
        echo "<th class=" . chr(34) . "cell" . chr(34) . ">$heading</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

function PopulateQueryTable($values,$Number)/******Updated*******/
{
    //$queryID = $values['ID'];

    echo "<tbody><tr class=" . chr(34) . "row" . ($Number) . chr(34) . ">";/*******Updated**********/
    foreach($values as $key=>$value)
    {
        if (!is_null($value))
        {
            echo "<td>$value</td>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<td></td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

function EndQueriesTable()
{
    echo "</tbody></table><br/>";
}

?>        


</body>
</html>
```

You can see that I added a counter that would update each time that a line was being processed into the table so that each row would have a different class.

Thank you to everyone who helped! I hope that this answer will help others with a similar problem.