# Can I style my site differently if my content/site is iframed?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

This is basically the opposite of this question - [CSS override body style for content in iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/css-override-body-style-for-content-in-iframe)

I have a CMS that provides data to a vendor CMS that is actually housed on the same server/domain.

The CMS is also used as a stand-alone.  So what we want to do is strip all of our headers, menus, and footers when displayed in the LMS.

So is there CSS I can use on my side that will only be used when the site is in an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use javascript. Taken from [How to identify if a webpage is being loaded inside an iframe or directly into the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t)

```
function inIframe () {
    try {
        return window.self !== window.top;
    } catch (e) {
        return true;
    }
}
if(inIframe()){
    // Change css
}
```