# How to target element inside iframe from css or javascript for styling

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to target an element that comes under the iframe tag to style with css or javascript?

any help will be apreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/css-override-body-style-for-content-in-iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access frames data only when your web-site (which is loaded inside this frame) support [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

If supports - you can access data using:

```
window.frames[0].document.getElementBy[Id | ClassName | ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access elements in an iframe by giving the element a class or id and making the proper adjustments in css. To access a class in css you should have a dot "." before the name of the class and "#" if you want to access an id. In javascript you can access the element by giving it an id and using getElementById("name of id") or giving it a class name and using getElementsByClass;

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to access to an  iframe from the parent page:

```
$('iframe').contentWindow.document.[body|head...][getElementById/ClassName...];
```