# I want to add a background image to this edit box, but the CSS is very complicated to me

Tags: html, css, edit, box

I need to place a background inside an edit box, but I've tried various CSS code for hours. Nothing works!

I can customise the CSS, but I do not have access to modify the source code.

[image: I want to add a background image inside this edit box]

Here's the source code of the section I am interested in:

```
<div id="cke_1_contents" class="cke_contents cke reset" role="presentation" style="height: 200px;">
<span id="cke_26" class="cke_voice_label>Press Alt 0 for help</span>
    <iframe class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" aria-describedby="cke_26" title="Rich Text Editor,form_essay_content" src="" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0">
    #document
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html dir="ltr" lang="en">
            <head></head>
            <body class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true">
            </body>
        </html>
    </html>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to add an image of a postcard in the background. Like so:

[image: I added an image as the backgound of the edit box via "Inspect element"]

I've tried so many combinations of CSS code to add the image. Fail. Fail. Fail. Here's two of them. Please try not to laugh...

```
<style>
    #cke_1_contents.cke_editable .cke_editable_themed .cke_contents_ltr .cke_show_borders {
       background-image: URL(http://www.moodurian.com/tornado/images/postcard-mini.jpg);
    }

    #cke_1_contents body {
       background-image: URL(http://www.moodurian.com/tornado/images/postcard-mini.jpg);
    }

</style>
```

Well, it didn't work. Any ideas, anyone? Please note that I cannot modify the source code. So I can't add any additional < div >< /div > tags or < span >< /span > tags. I can only enter custom CSS to modify the page elements.

Thanks for reading this.

Regards
Frankie Kam 
Malaysia

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to add CSS rules that target elements inside the `<iframe>`, is that correct? If so - you will need to add those CSS rules to a CSS document that the iframe itself loads - CSS rules from the parent document won't affect the iframe content.

I found a relevant question here: [CSS override body style for content in iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/css-override-body-style-for-content-in-iframe)

Comment: Hi rice119. Yes, I see. Having read the link you gave tells me that without access to the CSS code that the iframe loads, what I am trying to do can only be done in the Twilight Zone. Thank you all the same for pointing this out. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried editing the body in CSS? You could try something like

```
body {background-image: URL(http://www.moodurian.com/tornado/images/postcard-mini.jpg);}
```

I'm not sure why you're only able to edit the css and not the html. Seems a bit odd. Try this line of code and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply. I am using a cloud based service that runs an essay contest from within Facebook. See the tab named "Postcard Essay Competition": https://www.facebook.com/Kam-Fam-134012048474/app/395471657150951/
I can customise the CSS design by using an Admin backend GUI, but I do not have access to the source code. Here's how I customise the CSS: http://www.moodurian.com/tornado/images/customcode.jpg

I've tried the body { } code you suggested, but it doesn't work. Thanks anyway.