# How to hide elements of embedded iframe webpage

Tags: html, css, iframe

with iframe i embedded a page to my site like this.

```
<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" width="80%" height="200">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

now w3schools.com uses **w3-row w3-white w3-padding w3-hide-medium w3-hide-small** class in header and i want to hide it in my page?
How to perform this.?

Comment: You cannot modify the content of an iframed page unless the loaded page is within the same domain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS override body style for content in iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/css-override-body-style-for-content-in-iframe)

Comment: not same domain its differ domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your iframe loads an address from same domain, Set an id for your frame and do this:

```
var frame = window.frames['myFrame'];
$(frame).contents().find('p').hide();
```

Comment: I think the address is for example.