# How to change the size and other properties of the chat window

Tags: botframework

I have created a simple bot application using the botframework.  I am embedding the chat window in an iframe.  How can I control the chat window size and other properties like color, font etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can size the iframe but your options of modifying what's in it are limited - [CSS override body style for content in iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/css-override-body-style-for-content-in-iframe).

Here's how I typically integrate the provided Bot Framework's `iframe` with size control:

```
<div id="bot">
    <iframe src="https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/..." 
            style="height: 600px; width: 500px; resize: both;">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

If you want to have more control over how the web chat renders, you might want to look at other more advanced options of integrating their web chat. Read more on their github page: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat