# how can i remove the image form the frame

Tags: css

i need to remove this image form the frame and i tried this code but did not work

```css
.trevda-wide img {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: none !important;
}
```

this is the link of the site
http://saledirection.com/aldfsj.html
[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXObg.png)

Comment: `display: none` maybe

Comment: Include the HTML in your question; that page is not displaying the image. [see screenshot](http://imgur.com/pfMeBHG.png)

Comment: i tried it but did not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS override body style for content in iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/css-override-body-style-for-content-in-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Is the one you want to delete is this image?
[image]

If that the case then you can put `display: none` instead of `display: block` in the `.trevda-wide img`:
[image]

It works here, but if it somehow didn't work try putting `display:none!important`; this will make sure that the image is displayed as `none`.