# Remove hover effect on embedded twitter widget

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

How do I remove the dark hover effect on the following embedded twitter widget?

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/AV_Afrique" data-chrome="noheader nofooter transparent" data-theme="dark" data-tweet-limit="1" data-border-color="#272727">Tweets by AV_Afrique</a>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"
charset="utf-8"></script>
```

JsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mkc51zsc/

Comment: You won't be able to change the styles of any content rendered through an iframe unfortunately - not unless that content is served from your own server.

Comment: Is it possible to maybe alter the content after it has been loaded onto the page? I.e. suppress the code with JavaScript code?

Comment: Don't specify `data-theme="dark"` in your html tag?

Comment: @aaron that doesn't remove the hover effect

Comment: That removes the *dark* hover effect.

Comment: cant do with iframe. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/css-override-body-style-for-content-in-iframe

Comment: @aaron see: https://jsfiddle.net/mkc51zsc/3/

Comment: Read the docs and play with the various settings

Comment: See what? It works like I said.

Comment: @aaron - I don't want there to be a hover effect at all

Comment: You'll probably get a CORS error in your console if you try to manipulate the DOM of an `iframe` @methuselah - unless I'm mistaken, I believe this is what happened the last time I tried that. You can give it a go, although I don't think it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Override the

```
.timeline-Tweet:hover {
    background-color: rgba(24,50,35); 
}
```

with

```
.timeline-Tweet:hover {
    background-color:transparent; 
}
```

**Implementation**

**Option 1)** 
Wrap your link inside an element with unique Id e.g.

HTML

```
<div id="myId">
 <a>..twitter stuff </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 #myId .timeline-Tweet:hover {
        background-color:transparent; 
    }
```

**Option 2)**  Ugly fix

```
.timeline-Tweet:hover {
        background-color:transparent !important; 
    }
```