# How to change css in cross-domain iframe using jquery for cross-domain means external link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How i implement css in iframe my url is from cross-domain please help me how to do that.

Please check my code:-

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="1200" 
  id="cpatsframe" scrolling="no" src="https://Ghost.Org/jobs? 
       aggregator_id=180015&amp;embed=1" style="position: relative; 
    overflow: hidden; height: 2909px;" width="100%">Sorry, iframes are not 
  supported.</iframe>


   <script>

    $("#myframe").contents().find(".myclass").css('background', 'red');


    </script>
```

But this is not working Please tell me how i fix that or work it. Thanks alot In advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override body style for content in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/override-body-style-for-content-in-an-iframe)

Comment: No, My frame used the external link

Comment: I can't see `#myframe` in document?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if iframe is in same domain

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var iFrameDOM = $("iframe#cpatsframe").contents();
        iFrameDOM.find(".myclass").css("background-color", "red");
    });
</script>
```

> else There is no way to edit a Cross Domain IFrame.
>    You can manipulate domains within the same level, or lower in your domain chain but there is no way to made changes in cross domain iframe.