# Removing Youtube branding, title text etc. from an embedded iframe after it goes into fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, html, css

A pleasant good day to you all :)

I'm trying to remove the youtube branding from an iframe after it goes into fullscreen mode. You can see a sample of what I am attempting here: https://codepen.io/emjaisthebest/pen/ZmaKGv

```
HTML
<p><img data-video="XqC05_Oommw" alt="Play this video" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/Y7d42LJfkqQ/0.jpg"></p>
```

CSS
div:fullscreen .ytp-title-text .ytp-title-link .yt-uix-sessionlink .ytp-title .ytp-title-channel-logo .ytp-title-text .ytp-watch-later-icon .ytp-button .ytp-settings-button .ytp-hd-quality-badge .ytp-title-expanded-title  .ytp-youtube-button .ytp-button .yt-uix-sessionlink .ytp-menuitem-label .ytp-menuitem-content  .ytp-play-button .ytp-progress-list  .ytp-scrubber-button .ytp-swatch-background-color  .ytp-time-duration  .ytp-time-separator .ytp-time-current /*Not sure if you want to hide the current time, babe*/ .ytp-share-icon .ytp-pause-overlay .ytp-related-title .ytp-pause-overlay .ytp-suggestions  .ytp-expand-pause-overlay .ytp-fullscreen-button  .ytp-progress-bar-padding  .ytp-progress-bar .admin-bar .ytp-title-channel  .ytp-title-beacon  .ytp-chrome-top .ytp-show-watch-later-title .ytp-share-button-visible .ytp-show-share-title {
  display: none !important;
}

Javascript
if (!Element.prototype.requestFullscreen) {
    Element.prototype.requestFullscreen = Element.prototype.mozRequestFullscreen || Element.prototype.webkitRequestFullscreen || Element.prototype.msRequestFullscreen;
}

// Listen for clicks
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

```
// Check if clicked element is a video thumbnail
var videoId = event.target.getAttribute('data-video');
if (!videoId) return;

// Create iframe
var iframe = document.createElement('div');
iframe.innerHTML = '<p>x</p><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoId + '?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
var video = iframe.childNodes[1];

// Replace the image with the video
event.target.parentNode.replaceChild(video, event.target);

// Enter fullscreen mode
video.requestFullscreen();
```

}, false);

I know the css classes for all the elements I want to hide, but every time I try, it just does NOT work.

Is there anyone out there who can help me remove the ugly youtube branding? If yes, please help me as this is my first website and I would really love to make it aesthetically pleasing.

Edit #1: Someone was suggesting that my question was a possible duplicate of another question found here on stackoverflow, but that has nothing to do with removing the youtube branding from an iframe itself or modifying the iframe while it is in fullscreen mode. I, myself was trying to change it using the :fullscreen pseudo-class with no success. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override body style for content in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/override-body-style-for-content-in-an-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

What might work for you is the `modestbranding=1` parameter. For example:

```
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoId + '?rel=0&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1"
```

You can read more about it here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#modestbranding

Comment: Thank you, sir, for taking time out of your day to answer my question. Sadly, I tried this and it didn't help me.

But thanks once again for attempting to help me

Comment: I have updated your codepen, and it works for me (does not show the youtube logo). You can see it here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gQXoXE

Comment: Hey Matt; thank you for your help :)

But I am also interested in removing the ugly title, share button etc. from the video. All of the elements that I would like to hide are in the css section. 

Do you have any idea how I can remove those too?

Any help you offer would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can I suggest that you edit your question to reflect *exactly* what it is you are trying to achieve (maybe use pictures). Also, what makes the title/share button etc ugly? It feels like your time might be better spent focusing on your actual application ux, rather than the subtleties of youtube.