# Override CSS Styles in iframe CSS/HTML ONLY

Tags: css, iframe, styles, overriding, width

Im looking to override a piece of code from a Google form iframe, I want to adjust the width, but I have tried adding that style into my own css and adding `!important` after the width size but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the style I am trying to override:

```
.freebirdFormviewerViewCenteredContent {
    margin: auto;
    width: 640px;
}
```

Let me know if you guys have another solution I could try.

(also please only css and html answers, I cant add javascript/jquery.)

Harry.

Comment: please post jsfiddle

Comment: im new to this website, how do I do that?

Comment: go to https://jsfiddle.net/ and post your HTML or CSS in relevant boxes and share the link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y3tq08rm/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Comment: work perfect:https://jsfiddle.net/mwr7uj0e/

Comment: That jfiddle uses the css I want to change but, when you try to adjust the width it doesnt work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override body style for content in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/override-body-style-for-content-in-an-iframe)