# printing iframe doesn't include CSS

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, printing

I have an `iframe`, which includes `<button onclick="print()">print</button>`

```
var print = function(){
    parent.window.focus();
    window.print();
}
```

When I click on `<button>`, printing starts, but CSS is not included into printing. How can I force browser to include my CSS into printing?

Comment: Should that not be `parent.window.focus();
    parent.window.print();`

Comment: @mplungjan no, this makes the parent of iframe to print

Answer (score 0):

The CSS of the page inside the `iframe` must have the necessary [print CSS media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) in order to print as it is shown in the current browser.

i.e.

```
@media print {
    #my-element {
        color: red;
        /* all the styles you need */
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm including it with ``<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />``, but not even screen css is showing

Answer (score 0):

An iframe is a 'hole' in your page that displays another web page inside of it. The contents of the iframe is not in any shape or form part of your parent page.

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6495816/83542