# Make image keep aspect ratio when screen size changes

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have this iframe, which depending on the situation can contain a video, and if unavailable an image - the problem I seem to be having is that the image is not being responsive enough to scale itself based on the screen size -  it just cuts off the part that is outside the container.

This is what I currently have.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
}

.parent__wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <iframe class="parent__wrapper" src="https://placekitten.com/566/313" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/onze9y0a/3/

How do I make it avoid cutting the sides or buttons as the screen size changes?

Comment: @xmaster still same result..

Comment: include in buttons in your code for a better example

Comment: @xmaster not sure i understand, I've changed the percentage to viewport as you suggested  - still same response.

Comment: > You can just add the max-width: 100%; and height: auto; on image.

Comment: @MayankGupta that does not keep the aspect ratio of the image, and still cut the image..

Comment: The problem is your image is being loaded from some other html document which contains a image or video. So that html document should have necessary css which makes width and height of img element to 100%. Since you are loading it into iframe still it is a seperate page from its parent.

Comment: So writing styles in parent document will not cause anything to the elements that are resides in the iframe.

Comment: FYR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/override-body-style-for-content-in-an-iframe