# How would you embed RSS feeds into a static (or Hugo generated) website?

Tags: html, iframe, rss, frontend, hugo

I'm looking for advice on how to embed RSS feeds into either a static HTML website or a Hugo-generated template (mentioning that in case there's any Hugo-specific solutions).

My goal is to incorporate the most recent 3 blogposts from a specific RSS feed URL and display them (appropriately styling using CSS) on this external website that I'm working on.

All solutions I'm finding online are suggesting either outdated `gmodules` approaches or a 3rd party tool to accomplish this. It doesn't seem like it should be that complicated - by using the RSS feed URL in an `<iframe />` element, it renders, so is there any reason this is a not recommended approach?

Are there any best practices for embedding RSS feeds in an iframe?

Are there better methods for embedding RSS feeds on a website that don't involve third-party tools?

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The point of an `<iframe>` is to imbed a second independent website inside the current page. So, in fact, you cannot style the contents of an iframe using the CSS of the outer page.

You *can* style it with javascript (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13959836/10741691)) **if** they are in the same domain.

But if you are going to have to use javascript, it would be better to use AJAX.