# Can I hide content inside an iFrame from an external domain?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

I want to hide the logo from the iframe link. Is that possible?

```css
iframe {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="contentFrame" src="xyz.com/dashboard" style="width: 100%; height: 677px" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: An iframe is a 'hole' in your page that displays another web page inside of it. The contents of the iframe is not in any shape or form part of your parent page.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/override-body-style-for-content-in-an-iframe

Comment: Listen to me very carefully, we need the appropriate src.