# Styling imported element in HTML

Tags: html, css, object, formatting

So currently I am importing text as an object tag as so:

```
<object width="100%" height="500" data="M2History.txt" >
```

however when doing this, I currently am not getting any styles applied to the text, and its pasting into my site in a default format. When it gets imported it does as:
`<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">`

I tried to do styling on pre, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Can someone help with this? I have also tried to style other elements, such as body and object tags but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can add styles to an ***object*** element (not to it's inner content) with specific data attribute this way:

```
data=["M2History.txt"] {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

You cannot access object's inner content because this is iFrame, so CSS has no power. Please, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/override-body-style-for-content-in-an-iframe), it could be helpful. Good luck!
P.S. guide to data attributes [here](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-data-attributes/)