# Let 3rd party change styles of an iframe of my site

Tags: javascript, html, css, http, iframe

Let's say I am hosting `site2.com` and have `site2.com/frame.html` file that is simple as this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Site2.com frame</title>
  <style>
    body { background-color: yellowgreen; }
  </style>
</head>
<body id="site2-frame-body">
  <h1>This is site2.com frame for 3rd party use</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now say 3rd party website called `site1.com` wants to embed this content via `iframe` element like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Site1</title>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    #site2frame { border: 2px solid red; }
    #site2frame-body { background-color: blue !important; }
  </style>

  <iframe id="site2frame"
    title="Inline Frame Example"
    width="300"
    height="200"
    src="https://site2.com:3002/frame.html">
  </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

So I get this result in the Chrome browser when I open `site1.com` (ie. `site1.com` is playing the role of the 3rd party site here, while `site2.com` is site that hosts content to be embedded in inside iframe of other websites):

[image]

So the background of `body` element inside the frame is `yellowgreen` as set by the style in the `site2.com/frame.html`. When I try to override that with `blue` color as specified in the parent's website `site1.com:3002` this is not applied. I even used id selector with `!important` attribute but that is not propagated to inside of the frame content. Note that I am able to style the `iframe` element itself (with red border) but that is not my issue here.

So how can I enable this? Is there some standard way like enabling some http policy or setting some server headers `site2.com` that tells browsers "please allow CSS styling on embedded frames from this origin"? Note that frame content is cross-origin.

Note: this dev environment is set by me for practicing by using hosts file to point both `site1.com` and `site2.com` to 127.0.0.1 and I am running two node express instances to simulate different servers.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/override-body-style-for-content-in-an-iframe

Comment: This may be of some use, the basic premise is to change the iframe css using JS: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/find-and-change-css-on-elements-within-iframe-with-jquery/37125/3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't style 3rd party iframes because they are protected by the '[Same-origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)'.

That being said you could try sending the URL of a stylesheet as a GET parameter, and have `site2.com/frame.html` read this parameter and dynamically add it to its `<head>`.

For example, `site1.com` could create the iframe like so:

```html
<iframe id="site2frame"
  title="Inline Frame Example"
  width="300"
  height="200"
  src="https://site2.com:3002/frame.html?css=externalstylesheet.css">
</iframe>
```

And `site2.com/frame.html` could read the GET parameter, create a `link` element with the `href` set to the value of the parameter and append it to `document.head`:

```js
var css = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('css');
var stylesheet = document.createElement("link");
stylesheet.rel = "stylesheet";
stylesheet.href= css;
document.head.append(stylesheet);
```

[image: Edit pedantic-euclid-m120j]

Comment: This is the way to go. But for `site2.com` to remain secure despite this, you should also consider using a strong Content Security Policy (either in the form of HTTP header or <meta> tags): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

Answer (score 0):

You can't overwrite `iframe` style in other site!

Answer (score 0):

This script will do what you want

```
window.onload = function () {
    let myiFrame = document.getElementById("site2frame");
    let doc = myiFrame.contentDocument;
    doc.body.innerHTML =
      doc.body.innerHTML +
      "<style>body { background-color: blue;  !important} /* YOUR CSS*/</style>";
  };
```

This example was taken from this article: https://redstapler.co/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe/