# Need to customize the styling of iframe in css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

I have a iframe  `<div class="quiz-container" style="text-align: center;" data-quiz="#######" data-preview="true" data-offset="0" data-autoscroll="yes"></div>`

`<script src="https://marketingfx.leadshook.io/s/js_embed"></script>`

```html
<div class="quiz-container" style="text-align: center;" data-quiz="#######" data-preview="true" data-offset="0" data-autoscroll="yes"></div>
<script src="https://marketingfx.leadshook.io/s/js_embed"></script>
```

and the output is a form i want to edit the form css.
How can i edit the css?

Comment: Can't really test this with onscreen code. In the snippet, the form is not displaying.

Comment: i just need a simple way how to edit the css the form is not showing because `######` is passed in data-quiz attribute.

Comment: That doesn't look like an iframe. Whether or not it is actually an iframe is important.

Comment: That's true @HamzaKhalid273. You're not using an iframe tag.

Comment: my client provided me these things but i can also see the iframe in inspect element of my page.

Comment: Well, you can see something we cannot. It will be difficult to change the styling of an iframe from another domain. You can ask leadshook.io it's their stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The JS generates an iframe pointing to a different origin.

If you had control over that origin you could change the page that was loaded to have different CSS. Alternatively you could add an API (using [postMessage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue)) so JavaScript on your page could request CSS changes on the page in the frame.

It doesn't appear you do have control over `https://marketingfx.leadshook.io`, however, so you can't do that.

It is someone else's webpage. You can't control how someone else's webpage looks.

This does appear to be a service that `https://marketingfx.leadshook.io` provides. They might provide a way to do that. Consult their documentation or talk to your contacts there.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered on Stack Overflow previously. Please see [Override body style for content in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/override-body-style-for-content-in-an-iframe)

There are several answers in that post which should help.