# Change body background color in an iframe using one css file

Tags: html, css, iframe

Using a iframe where I call a site from my webspace, Using one css file with `body {background-color: #222}`.

The iframe src also use this CSS file. The Problem is that the body in the iframe need another background-colour.

tried

```
iframe>body { background-color: #other }
```

Any idea or suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume the iframe takes up a smaller portion of your site. In that case I would advice you to simply use a div with the same size of the iframe is loaded, and giving this div the proper background-color.

OR: include a style property in the source of the iframe page:

```
<head>
    <style>body {background-color:#COLOR}</style>
</head>
```

Comment: Only works if the iFrame is from the same parent domain

Answer (score 5):

This question is similar to [How to apply css to iframe content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714880/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe-content). Basically you can use jQuery to change the CSS properties in the iframe

```
$('#yourIframe').contents().find('body').css({
    background-color: '#333333'
});
```

**Edit:**
You may need to add that when the iframe loads:

```
$('#yourIframe').load(function(){ 
    $(this).contents().find('body').css({
        background-color: '#333333'
    });
});
```

Comment: Only works if the iFrame is from the same parent domain

Comment: That is because of the same origin policy. It s a critical security mechanism to prevent someone loading up just about any site in a iframe and changing stuff there to serve a ulterior motive.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that a Javascript can modify only properties of iframe with the same origin of the site, otherwise you'll get a Security Error.

Protocols, domains and ports must match.

Answer (score 2):

ive used this and it works for me. (and its sooooo easy!)

in your CSS file put:

**iframe { background-color:orange; }**

Just change the "orange" to whatever color you need.
Thats it!

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

In the page that the iframe contains, link another stylesheet and then change all the CSS styles that you wish to.

Comment: I wanne avoid to use 2 css files

Comment: have you tried adding a class to the iframe and then referring it by .Class>body {style : style }

Answer (score 0):

using Javascript We can add Background Color to Iframe

```
 var x = document.getElementById("myframe");
    var y = (x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);
    if (y.document)y = y.document;
    y.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Reference [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_iframe_contentdocument)