# HTML Removing Background from within Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm wondering if there is any way to remove background color from within Iframe original site.. It is only a white color. Can I use javascript??

Comment: used to this iframe html body{background:#fff;}

Comment: Using jQuery or pure javascript solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299515/change-body-background-color-in-an-iframe-using-one-css-file

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("YourIframeId").contentWindow.document.body.style.backgroundColor="blue";
```

Answer (score 1):

if the iframe have the same domain as your page you can achieve this via javascript, with something like this

```
document.getElementById('IFRAMEID').contentDocument.body.style.background = "transparent";
```

then you'll need to add the transparency attribute to the iframe

```
ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true"
```

Comment: i't is not my domain, it is a third party webmail server login page.. i't has an ugly white background:)

Comment: unfortunately because of the same-origin restriction you can't edit an iframe with a different domain, take a look here for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy
Try to check if they have any API or params to pass to customize the iframe.