# how to change CSS on the youtube subscribe widget

Tags: jquery, css, youtube, widget, subscribe

I have a wordpress blog and am wanting to put the youtube subscribe widget in the widgets bar.
The only thing is that it is really ugly :(

It is an iframe so I cant change the CSS easily but I think maybe I can do it with jQuery?

```
<iframe id="fr" src="http://www.youtube.com/subscribe_widget?p=[add  YouTube Username here]" style="overflow: hidden; height: 105px; width:  300px; border: 0;" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

I just want to get rid of the black border really.

would love some help.
Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible to do with jQuery - this kind of activity is blocked by the same-origin policy. It's a useful thing to do, but also opens up all kinds of security holes.

However, the widgets themselves are customizable. Take a look [here](http://monkeyraptor.johanpaul.net/2013/04/stylized-youtube-subscription-widget.html) for some ideas.

Comment: Thanks blueberry fields! some one told me I can do it with something like this but I guess the Same origin policy stops this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714880/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe-content

Comment: The question you linked even says: " Mind you, it has to be same domain/ports etc, so that's why my example features jsfiddle in the iframe". It only works if you're changing code that's served from your own site - you won't be able to modify youtube's frame.