# How to point to an id under 1 frame css

Tags: html, css

I have following code snippet:

```
...    
<iframe id="srCashOverviewDashboard" class="srCashOverviewDashboard" width="100%" height="1000px" frameborder="0" name="srCashOverviewDashboard" scrolling="no" rdiframeadditionalscrollheightadded="" rdiframeadditionalscrollwidthadded="" onload=" iframeResize(this)" rdiframefixedwidth="True" data-hiddensource="rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Dashboard.CashLevel1&rdRequestCache=3707323034&rdSubReport=True&rdResizeFrame=True" src="rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Dashboard.CashLevel1&rdRequestCache=3707323034&rdSubReport=True&rdResizeFrame=True" style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 1000px;">
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html id="yui_3_1_1454057078100_124" class="yui3-js-enabled" xmlns:rdxslextension="urn:rdXslExtension" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" style="margin: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; cursor: auto;">

  <head>
    <body id="yui_3_1_1454057078100_106" onload="rdBodyLoad()" style="margin: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
      <div style="display: none; background-image: url('rdTemplate/rdWaitAll.gif')"></div>
      <div id="yui_3_1_1454057078100_1056" class="yui3-widget rdquicktip yui3-widget-positioned rdquicktip-hidden" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">
      <div style="display: none; background-image: url('rdTemplate/rdWaitAll.gif')"></div>
      <div style="display: none; background-image: url('rdTemplate/rdWaitAll.gif')"></div>
      <div id="yui_3_1_1454057078100_345" class="yui3-widget rdquicktip yui3-widget-positioned rdquicktip-hidden" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">
      <div style="display: none; background-image: url('rdTemplate/rdWaitAll.gif')"></div>
      <div id="yui_3_1_1454057078100_237" class="yui3-dd-shim" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 9999; overflow: hidden; background-color: red; display: none; height: 5px; width: 5px;"></div>
      <div style="display: none; background-image: url('rdTemplate/rdWaitAll.gif')"></div>
      <div id="yui_3_1_1454057078100_56" class="yui3-widget rdquicktip yui3-widget-positioned rdquicktip-hidden" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">
      <div style="display: none; background-image: url('rdTemplate/rdWaitAll.gif')"></div>
      <form id="yui_3_1_1454057078100_107" method="POST" name="rdForm">
        <input id="rdCSRFKey1" type="hidden" value="cb35ed6b-fbd0-4f81-947f-db1b4e3a8531" name="rdCSRFKey">
        <div id="rdMainBodyStart"></div>
        <div id="rdMainBody">
        ...    
        </div>
```

I want to add style for this `rdMainBody`. There are more specific `#rdMainBody` ID's on my webpage but I only want to add style to this one.

Everything from ID's and classes are auto generated, except the iframe, it contains an ID `srCashOverviewDashboard`and a class `srCashOverviewDashboard`.

So I was trying to add something in my css file like
`.srCashOverviewDashboard #rdMainbody` or `#srCashOverviewDashboard #rdMainbody`

But this doesn't seem to work, do I do something wrong or do I need to do something else?

Greetings

Comment: what is `cashOverviewDashboard`? should it be `srCashOverviewDashboard`?

Comment: yes, little typo in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's .content() function to access it.

```
$('yourIframe').contents().find('#yourItemYouWantToChange').css({
    opacity: 0,
    color: 'purple'
});
```

See also this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pPqGe/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714880/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe-content) post.

Comment: I can't use Jquery actually, needs to be solved with css

Comment: I don't think its possible with CSS only. If you have direct access to the page in the iframe, you may add the css there.

Comment: In that case, I'm screwed.